# Comparator operator with string in sql query

Tags: sql

What does sql query actually compare when we use comparator with string data type ?

```
select * from users where name>='abcd';
```

Answer (score 0):

`>=` compares two strings based on the collation defined for the string.

In general, this means that they are compared alphabetically.  So your query would return anything that would follow `'abcd'` in the dictionary (plus `'abcd'`), including `'abcde'` and `'zzz'`.

You don't specify the database you are using.  Whatever it is, it certainly has documentation on collations and character sets.

Comment: suppose we have two users entries one with name = 'ajay' and another with name = '2018'.
then what should be the result for query
```select * from users where name>='201899''```

Comment: That depends on the collation, whether digits are bigger or smaller than lower-case letters, which they are for ASCII character sets.

Answer (score 0):

Strings have a natural, lexicographical order. This query will select all the names that come "after" `abcd`, such as `bob` (since `b` is after `a`) or `allen` (since `l` is after `b`).

Answer (score 0):

`>` and `<` and `=` means that they are compared alphabetically when that happens, a `BOOLEAN` value is returned (i.e., a `TRUE`, `FALSE`, or `NULL`).

In your example, the SQL code would return results that were "greater than" or *after* `acbd`, so thinks like `bbbb` or `z` presumably.